How to redirect to address like localhost:port/path1/path2/path3
First of all, I'm a bit newbie with Nginx.
I'm trying to deploy an application in a server, and want Nginx to redirect to it. My case is:

If users type [publicIP]:[appPort]/path1/path2/path3, it works.
Obviusly, this is not friendly at all, so I want to achieve the case that a user only needs to type mysubdomain.domain.com and be redirected to [publicIP]:[appPort]/path1/path2/path3 but only showing mysubdomain.domain.com in the browser, not the full path (I know that the DNS must to be resolved in my hosting partner, and is already achieved. mysubdomain.domain.com is already "pointing" to [publicIP] and working).
I have tried lots of configurations like, with no luck:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysubdomain.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://publicIP:appPort/path1/path2/path3;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost/ http://localhost:appPort/;
    }
}



What can I do?

Well, I have been trying, and when I use proxy_pass http://publicIP:appPort (without the rest of the path), Nginx redirect to the port, but when I use the full path in proxy_pass (proxy_pass http://publicIP:appPort/path1/path2/path3), it isn't working.

Please add more details, what is the exact request you make, what is the expected output and what is the exact output you get. "Not working" tells no information about the possible root cause.

You need to set proxy_redirect off:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysubdomain.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://publicIP:appPort/path1/path2/path3;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Keep the URL in the browser as mysubdomain.domain.com
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

Hope this helps!

Still not working... I don't know why, but seems that mixing redirecting port and path isn't working. Thank you for your efforts!
